# Replacing Probabilities with Densities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I recently read through the calculation of the probability that one independent exponential RV is less than another and have been left with a nagging question.

[image]

Thank you very much for any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very legitimate question to ask. I think the first integral is a terrible abuse of notation since really, for any continuous RV, $P(X=x)=0$.

The intention is to condition $X_1 < X_2$ on $X_2$, and then integrate over $X_2$ which is the correct way of doing it, which is indeed the second integral.

Another way to derive this is to integrate their joint probability over the region where $X_1 < X_2$ and again the second integral will be obtained in one step...

Comment: Strongly agree with this comment. It is, indeed, a terrible abuse of notation. Note that $\mathbb{P}\left(X=x\right)$ is the "pdf" when $X$ is a discrete random variable (technically, the pdf would be known as a pmf, a probability mass function).